# Use each input argument in GNU Parallel as a working directory

Tags: gnu-parallel

I'm trying to use GNU Parallel to run a command for each input argument, using that argument as the command's working directory (without appending it to the command line).

Basically, what I need to do is:

```
/foo -> "cd /foo; mycmd"
/bar -> "cd /bar; mycmd"
/baz -> "cd /baz; mycmd"
```

---

Parallel has `--workdir` which seems to do what I want by virtue of supporting `{}` replacement strings:

> --workdir mydir
> --wd mydir
>
> Jobs will be run in the dir mydir. The default is the current dir for the local machine, and the login dir for remote computers.
> <...>
> mydir can contain GNU parallel's replacement strings.

To prevent the argument from being appended to the command line, I tried to use `-n0` or `-N0`:

> --max-args max-args
> -n max-args
>
> Use at most max-args arguments per command line.
> <...>
> -n 0 means read one argument, but insert 0 arguments on the command line.

However, that doesn't seem to work:

```
$ mkdir -p $HOME/{foo,bar,baz}
$ printf '%s\n' $HOME/{foo,bar,baz} | parallel --workdir '{}' -n0 'pwd'
parallel: Error: Cannot change into non-executable dir : No such file or directory
```

Note the space before the `:`, which is not a typo in GNU parallel, but an indication that the workdir got evaluated to an empty string. This becomes evident if I prepend a fixed string to `{}`, in which case all pwds print that fixed string:

```
$ printf '%s\n' $HOME/{foo,bar,baz} | parallel --workdir '/{}' -N0 'pwd'       
/
/
/
```

---

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @don_crissti Not a permission problem. The problem is that the workdir evaluates to an empty string, which becomes evident by prepending a fixed path to `{}`, in which case all pwds print that fixed string. Either way, `GNU parallel 20231122`.

Comment: @don_crissti It's kinda hard to notice but there's a space before `:` in parallel's output, which gives a hint as to what's happening. I've updated the question now.

Comment: Oh, ok, sorry for not paying attention... I now see that you're also using `-n0` which explains the error. `parallel` is not using any argument so `{}` is replaced with nothing hence the error...  replace your command after the pipe with `parallel  -n0 echo '{}'` and you'll see what happens - `parallel` will run `echo`  three times (the number of arguments) with without using any of the args (due to `-n0`) as arguments for the command so you get three empty lines...

Comment: @don_crissti Yes, I can imagine how that happens, but I have expected the argument to `--workdir` be exempt from the effects of `-n0`. In any case, the general question still stands: how do I make `parallel` use each input argument as the command's cwd and at the same time prevent that argument from being appended to the command line?

Comment: Well, the man page is quite clear: _"If the command line contains no replacement strings then {} will be appended to the command line."_... So either do as Stéphane suggests or use a trick to consume the argument that you specify explicitly i.e.  run something like `... | parallel --workdir '{}' -n1 ': {}; pwd'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the easiest would be:

```
printf '%s\n' $HOME/{foo,bar,baz} | parallel 'cd {} && myprg'
```

You *can* use `--workdir`, but it is clearly not meant for this situation. GNU Parallel normally wants a replacement string in the command template, and you want `{}` to contain the argument for `--workdir`.

Using `-n0` will not help, because then `{}` will be empty and then `--workdir` will fail: `{}` evaluates to the same string no matter where it is used.

So the workaround is to use `{}`, but use it where it does no harm:

```
parallel --workdir {} 'true dummy {}; myprg' ::: $HOME/{foo,bar,baz}
```

Or use `{==}` to generate a static part of the command:

```
parallel --workdir {} '{= $_="myprg" =}' ::: $HOME/{foo,bar,baz}
```

Personally, I prefer the `cd {}` version: I think easier to see what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

AFAICT `--workdir` is not meant to have all the `{...}` directives in its arguments expanded. GNU `parallel` runs a shell anyway to interpret the code you give, so you can always do:

```
... | PARALLEL_SHELL=sh parallel 'CDPATH= cd -P -- {} && mycmd'
```

(here forcing the shell to be `sh` instead of relying on `parallel`'s heuristics to determine which shell to run, and working around some of the problems with `cd`)

If you don't need any of the features of GNU `parallel`, you could use GNU `xargs` in combination with GNU `env` and avoid GNU `parallel` and shell overhead and the unreliable `cd` shell builtin:

```
... | xargs -rd '\n' -P8 -I{} env -C {} mycmd
```

Comment: Now I know more about `cd` than I ever wanted to :-) Thanks.